# php xpath select nodes based on values of two attributes (edit) AND its parents attributes

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

xpath 1.0 - I had to change the approach, because the XML has changed.

I need to pull the

```
t-Attribute FROM the <d>-node WHERE its 
    raw-Attribute = 10 
    AND its parent-node's <scale> gender-Attribute = "*" OR "m" 
    AND the age-Attribute = "*" OR "39-59"  

<scales>
    <scale id="1" gender="*" age="*">
        <d scid="hi" raw="10" t="76" />
        <d scid="pn" raw="12" t="80" />
    </scale>
    <scale id="2" gender="m" age="*">
        <d scid="hi" raw="8" t="79" />
        <d scid="pn" raw="2" t="50" />
    </scale>
    <scale id="3" gender="*" age="19-39">
        <d scid="hi" raw="0" t="48" />
        <d scid="pn" raw="10" t="49" />
    </scale>
</scales>
```

For my original objective, Passerby's solution worked like a charm, but I can't figure out how to solve the additional task...

```
$result=$xml->xpath('//scale[@gender="*" or @gender="m"][@age="*" or @age="39-59"]');
```

Here's my original task...

I want to select nodes from xml where two attributes hold specific values. I am using simplexml, so the xpath has to be 1.0.

XML snippet:

```
<scales>
    <scale id="1" gender="*" age="*">
        <d>5</d>
        <d>9</d>
    </scale>
    <scale id="2" gender="m" age="*">
        <d>3</d>
        <d>0</d>
    </scale>
    <scale id="3" gender="*" age="19-39">
        <d>12</d>
        <d>19</d>
    </scale>
</scales>
```

Now, I want to select all `<scale>` that have...

```
(gender="*" OR gender="m") AND (age="*" OR age="39-59")
```

in my example the ones with id=1 and id=2

I know how to do it with 1 attribute, but without the OR / AND conditions...

```
$scales=$xml->xpath("//scale[@gender='m']");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
//scale[@gender="*" or @gender="m"][@age="*" or @age="39-59"]
```

[Live demo](http://3v4l.org/mXbg3)

```
$str=<<<XML
<scales>
    <scale id="1" gender="*" age="*">
        <d>5</d>
        <d>9</d>
    </scale>
    <scale id="2" gender="m" age="*">
        <d>3</d>
        <d>0</d>
    </scale>
    <scale id="3" gender="*" age="19-39">
        <d>12</d>
        <d>19</d>
    </scale>
</scales>
XML;
$xml=simplexml_load_string($str);
$result=$xml->xpath('//scale[@gender="*" or @gender="m"][@age="*" or @age="39-59"]');
foreach($result as $node)
{
    echo $node->attributes()->id."\n";
}
```

Comment: had to adjust my objective with this xpath, could you take a look at it, if it's ok for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158314/php-xpath-retrieving-attribute-values-based-on-multiple-attributes-and-parent-at#comment21344739_15158314