# php xpath retrieving attribute-values based on multiple attributes and parent-attributes

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

I need to select nodes from xml, conditions see below. I am using simplexml, so the xpath has to be 1.0.

XML snippet:

```
<scales>
    <scale id="1" gender="*" age="*">
        <d scid="hi" raw="10" t="76" />
        <d scid="pn" raw="12" t="80" />
    </scale>
    <scale id="2" gender="m" age="*">
        <d scid="hi" raw="8" t="79" />
        <d scid="pn" raw="2" t="50" />
    </scale>
    <scale id="3" gender="*" age="19-39">
        <d scid="hi" raw="0" t="48" />
        <d scid="pn" raw="10" t="49" />
    </scale>
</scales>
```

Now, I want to select the `t`-Attribute of a `<d>` node that has...

```
 raw="10" AND scid="hi"

 $result=$xml->xpath('//d[@scid="hi"][@raw="10"]/@t');
```

And its parent-node `<scale>` has...

```
(gender="*" OR gender="m") AND (age="*" OR age="39-59")

$result=$xml->xpath('//scale[@gender="*" or @gender="m"][@age="*" or @age="39-59"]');
```

I'd like to get this with 1 xpath-statement from my simplexml-object `$xml`.

Comment: There's an error in your XML at least raw="12 is missing a " which may not be hleping or is that just a mistype on here ?

Comment: can you provide some actual php code like how you're attempting to query it at the moment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just combine your two XPath query...

[Live demo](http://3v4l.org/Fo9iW)

```
$str=<<<XML
<scales>
    <scale id="1" gender="*" age="*">
        <d scid="hi" raw="10" t="76" />
        <d scid="pn" raw="12" t="80" />
    </scale>
    <scale id="2" gender="m" age="*">
        <d scid="hi" raw="8" t="79" />
        <d scid="pn" raw="2" t="50" />
    </scale>
    <scale id="3" gender="*" age="19-39">
        <d scid="hi" raw="0" t="48" />
        <d scid="pn" raw="10" t="49" />
    </scale>
</scales>
XML;
$xml=simplexml_load_string($str);
foreach($xml->xpath('//scale[@gender="*" or @gender="m"][@age="*" or @age="39-59"]/d[@scid="hi"][@raw="10"]/@t') as $t)
{
    echo $t;
}
```

Outputs `76`.

Answer (score 0):

ok quick read into xpath seems like you can do attribute matches something like this

```
 $path = "(scale[@gender=\"*\"]|scale[@gender=\"m\"]) & (scale[@age=\"*\"]|scale[@age=\"39-59\"])";
 $scale= $xml->xpath($path);
```

This should return you the actual scale tag you want.
Then you can foreach loop through the  tags within the returned $scale and pull the standard attributes using something like this (note not accurate but right concept)

```
foreach($scale->d[0]->attributes() as $a => $b => $c) {
    echo "t=$c\"\n";
}
```